# Java 8 Stream Filer based on Object property

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to get the sum of all values from a map using streams in java 8. Below is the Collection i have:

```
Map<BigDecimal, List<Object>> map = ...... //some elements in this map
```

Lets say Object has below properties:

```
BigDecimal previousAmount;
int typeCode;
```

I am trying to get the sum of all previousAmount for each object in a list for all keys. Below is what i have came up with:

```
BigDecimal previousAmt = map.values().stream().flatMap(List::stream)
            .map(Object::previousAmount).reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, (a, b) -> a.add(b));
```

This is giving me the sum of all elements in the list and for all keys correctly. But i am trying to filter and get the sum only if the typeCode is greater than 10.

Can any one please suggest how to filter the above stream using typeCode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the [Stream.filter()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) method:

```
BigDecimal previousAmt = map.values().stream().flatMap(List::stream)
    .filter(i -> i.getTypeCode() > 10) // filters the stream
    .map(MyObject::getPreviousAmount)
    .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. @SamuelPhilipp . Is there any way i can see if the type is equal to 10? instead of >10? I am getting an error if i try to do that as said above :(

Comment: What's the error? of course you can change the the condition, just replace it!

Comment: My bad. Its working Sorry. Just the wrong syntax and this link : https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-streams-filter-examples/ helped me. thanks a lot the response.